# Twilio nodejs in es module

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

**How to import twilio into nodejs es module?**

```
const client = require("twilio")(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 6):

In the library (you can see [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/f120b4b011c4f5d25c5acf47bc23679e52799353/lib/index.js)):

```js
module.exports = function(accountSid, authToken, opts) {
    return new Twilio(accountSid, authToken, opts);
}
```

`module.exports = Car` would be equivalent to `export default Car`

So you can import the module with:

```js
import twilio from "twilio";
//     ^ this will select default export

const client = twilio(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import * as Twilio from 'twilio';

const YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;


const client = Twilio(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);

client.messages
  .create({
     body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
     from: '+15017122661',
     to: '+15558675310'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

Make sure you install `twilio` correctly.

Comment: I get this error message  = const client = Twilio(sidTwilio, tokenTwilio);
               ^

TypeError: Twilio is not a function

Comment: There was a problem with the code but it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is here because they are having this issue with AWS Lambda Nodejs 18.x and AWS SDK v3 requiring ES6 imports, the other solutions listed didn't work for me (I would still get the error `"Cannot find package 'twilio' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"`).

Instead, I had to create a seperate `twilio-loader.js` file in my Lambda function:

```
//imports twilio as commonJS
const twilio = require('twilio');

const createTwilioClient = (accountSid, authToken) => {
  return twilio(accountSid, authToken);
};

module.exports = { createTwilioClient };
```

And then in my `index.mjs` file, I included the lines

```
import { createTwilioClient } from './twilio-loader.js';

const { TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN } = process.env;
const twilioClient = createTwilioClient(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
```